# Is there a way to connect to remote emacs with local emacs configure?

Tags: emacs, emacsclient

On my laptop, I tried the emacs `server-start` to start a server daemon, and then i use `emacsclient -c` to connet the server.

It is awesome.

I have a PC used like a server for some guys using the same account -- root.
So on the PC , there is no `.emacs` file or `.emacs.d` dir.

I write the code using emacs with `.emacs.d` dir on my laptop and then `scp` or `async` to remote PC for other guys.

I wonder if I can start a emacs server on PC, and I use the laptop with laptop `.emacs.d` configure, then connect to remote PC to editor some file.

If it work, I can use any laptop without copy the code on it.

Can it be solved?

Comment: Can you clarify exactly what you mean by "configure", and why it might "influence another user"? Could you give examples? I think that would make the question easier to understand.

Comment: If you, by "configure" mean your emacs init file (e.g. `~/.emacs`) and other things -- why don't you place them under version control and have local sandboxes both on your local machine (so that you can use Emacs locally) and the server (when you connect remotely)? Another approach might be to run Emacs locally and edit files remotely, using something like `/user@host:filename`?